# paypal buy now return

Tags: paypal

input type="hidden" name="rm" value="0" after ending transaction Paypal return at URL define in input type="hidden" name="return" **WITHOUT**  payment variables included in GET,

If I set input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" after ending transaction Paypal return at URL define in input type="hidden" name="return" WITH  payment variables included in POST, but when browser alerts that are leaving secure connection if the buyer doesn't click OK the redirect **always start WITHOUT** payment variables included in POST...

I need that return URL have payment variables included in GET, what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to use the GET method, the betther method to use here instead of setting the return URL and the rm variable, would be to use PDT.  This will always return the variables as a get method, and it will allow you to validate the variables being returned, that they came from PayPal.